# Adjust the vertical position of FlowLayout components?

Tags: java, flowlayout

I tried to adjust the vertical position, I looked at all the settings, unfortunately I could not find it.

How can I set the y position of the 2nd button?
I want the y position at the top.

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(91, 95));
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("New button");
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using something like this to set a buffer area to manually affect where my components position. you have to keep adjusting the dimension until you get it where you want though. There may be a better way, but I haven't found it yet.

```
frame.add(someComponent);
frame.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100, 0)));
frame.add(otherComponent);
```

Comment: Not sure if, after more than two years, the OP is still waiting for an answer, however I think that `Box` is intended for use with [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) and not `FlowLayout`. By the way, have you taken the [tour]?

Comment: Lol yeah 2 years is a while. Box may be commonly used with BoxLayout but it's working so far. If I find a better way I'll swap it out. My problem was that BoxLayout can't be shared, so my new window using static variables couldn't use it.